K9s filter with OR operator
How I can filter the values on the screen after pressing / with OR operators ?
i.e:
In Deployments I want to filter those that contain secure or plain ?

K9s filters support Regex2,
In any screen press / and the it use | between the values
For example:
secure|plain


see more:
https://k9scli.io/topics/commands/
